# Grabar fecha en tabla de mysql

Tags: mysqli

Tengo este codigo, en el que tomo una fecha y la quiero guardar en una tabla y me dal el Sgte. error, no me doy cuenta donde puede estar

Problemas en el select:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 71

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problema</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$v1 = $_POST['Pre'];
echo $v1;
$hoy = date("j, n, Y"); 
echo $hoy;
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","htl") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");

mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into  tarifas
                            (nr,
                            single,
                            iva1,
                            doble,
                            iva2,
                            triple,
                            iva3,
                            cuadr,
                            iva4,
                            dpto2p,
                            ivad2,
                            dpto3p,
                            ivad3,
                            dpto4p,
                            ivad4,
                            dpto5p,
                            ivad5,
                            dpto6p,
                            ivad6,
                            dpto7p,
                              ivad7,
                              dpto8p,
                            ivad8,
                            suite,
                            ivasui,
                            pecomp,
                            mediap,
                            desayuno,
                            almcena,
                            bcomun1,
                            bcomun2,
                            bcomun3,
                            bcomun4,
                fecha)
                            VALUES

        ('$_POST[Pre]',
        '$_REQUEST[valsing]',
        '$_REQUEST[iva1]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdob]',
      '$_REQUEST[iva2]',
      '$_REQUEST[valtrip]',
      '$_REQUEST[iva3]',
      '$_REQUEST[valcuad]',
      '$_REQUEST[iva4]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep2]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad2]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep3]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad3]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep4]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad4]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep5]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad5]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep6]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad6]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep7]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad7]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdep8]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivad8]',
      '$_REQUEST[valsuit]',
      '$_REQUEST[ivasu]',
      '$_REQUEST[pcomp]',
      '$_REQUEST[valmp]',
      '$_REQUEST[valdesa]',
      '$_REQUEST[alcen]',
      '$_REQUEST[baco1]',
      '$_REQUEST[baco2]',
      '$_REQUEST[baco3]',
      '$_REQUEST[baco4]',
      '$_REQUEST[hoy]'")
                          or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error($conexion));
  echo "El mail fue modificado con exito";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El editor de la pagina me desacomodó todo, si necesitan acalaracion, pidan, gracias

Comment: Todas las claves que sacas de `$_POST` o de `$_REQUEST` deben ir entre comillas dobles o simples, por ejemplo: `$_POST["Pre"]` o `$_REQUEST["valtrip"]` ... tienes que hacerlo con todas. Yo en tu caso para no escribir un código confuso, usaría variables y operadores ternarios, así se evalúa al mismo tiempo cada POST o REQUEST. También, para un futuro, considera asegurar tu código, el mismo es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.

Comment: No cierras bien los paréntesis, creo que '$_REQUEST[hoy]'") debería ser '$_REQUEST[hoy]')")  antes del or, es un poco difícil de leer, pero no cierras el paréntesis de values.

Comment: Este sería un ejemplo de las variables que digo, con operadores ternarios: `$pre=empty($_POST["Pre"]) ? " '' " :  "'.$_POST["Pre"].'" ; $valsing=empty($_REQUEST["valsing"]) ? " '' " : "'.$_REQUEST["valsing"].'";  //etc.` Luego, usas las variables en la consulta: `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ($pre,$valsing ...)` algo **muy importante**  es que será al crear la variable donde encerrarás entre comillas simples `'` los valores que lo requieran. Así evitarás errores y confusiones de comillas dobles/simples. Y tu código quedará libre de posibles `Undefined index` al haber evaluado con `empty`...

Answer (score 0):

Los index de cada uno de los valores que recojes en el REQUEST o POST provienen de una constante? Es decir, $_POST[Pre] existe Pre como constante? De no ser así tienes que colocar las comillas para indicar el indice a buscar.

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into  tarifas(nr, single, iva1, ....)
             VALUES
            ('".$_POST['Pre']."', '".$_REQUEST['valsing']."', '".$_REQUEST['iva1']."', ... )") 
             or die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Al final de la consulta necesitas cerrar el parentesis del VALUES (

```
    '".$_REQUEST['hoy']."')")
```

> Una sugerencia sería verificar que cada uno de los parametros $_REQUEST a insertar al menos se reciban, y en caso contrario colocar algún valor por defecto.

```
$_REQUEST['valsing'] = isset($_REQUEST['valsing']) ? $_REQUEST['valsing'] : "";
```

> O algo similar.

Comment: Estan muy buenos sus consejos, algunos funciona y otros empeoran el sintoma, mi pregunta concreta es por que me sale "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 71" y por que no graba la fecha en la tabla...

Comment: @Fernando el error indica que la consulta no esta bien estructurada de acuerdo a las reglas del sistema gestor de base de datos y/o a la estructura que has definido para la tabla. Puede aparecer por errores con las comillas, no estar escrita correctamente, falta de campos... En cuanto al tema de la fechas suele haber problemas por como esta definido el campo en la tabla, es decir que el dato a ingresar debe de tener un formato determinado que no se corresponda con lo que intentas ingresar. Comprueba esto. Un saludo.